# Apple Developer Enterprise Program for version control

Tags: ios, git, version-control, app-store

My friend recently joined a new company as an iOS app developer. Here, they conduct PROD testing using an Apple Developer Enterprise Program account before uploading apps to the App Store. When I asked why, he said team members said it's for version management.

This process were handled by the previous employees, but since they have all left the company, nobody really knows the the exact reason now.

In my opinion, we could just create a branch for PROD version in the remote Git, or create a local branch and, if there are no issues with PROD, merge it into the master branch in the remote. Is my thinking off?

As far as I know, the Enterprise Plan isn't made for this purpose; it's supposed to be for internal apps.

Comment: You are 1000% correct.  Their setup is completely without purpose. Simply upload the development versions of your app (whatever branch, doesn't matter) to test flight as usual for the main app.  You then test it internally from test flight. That's it.

Comment: It's nothing to do with git branches. The main advantage of an enterprise build is that you don't need to manage devices or TestFlight users. If you use an adhoc build then all of your test devices need to be in the provisioning profile. If you use TestFlight then all of your testers need to be added to your apple developer account (or, if you set them up as external testers you need to go through TestFlight review for new versions). Depending on the number of testers and how often they change an enterprise build may be simpler than managing the testers.

Comment: As long as the testers using the enterprise build are all employees or contractors then the use of the enterprise program is in compliance. If the enterprise builds are being made available to non employees then they are in violation of the terms of the program.